# Getting file path from Business Objects Enterprise programmatically

Tags: c#, business-objects, crystal-reports-server

Within the Crystal Reports APIs that come standard with Visual Studios, is there any way to extract a file path from a report existing on a Business Objects Enterprise server? We create a ReportDocument object and load it using an InfoStore and an EnterpriseSession. We're looking for a way to programatically extract the file path name so we can use it for metadata in our extraction process. Also, we tried using the FileName property in the ReportDocument class, but it just returns a report CUID.

If we can't figure out a way to do this, we will just do this programatically through a recursive function, but I would definitely *prefer* to find a property that has this stored.

Comment: Let me verify I understand the question.  You have a ReportDocument, InfoStore, and EnterpriseSession object.  From the ReportDocument you would like to get Input File Repository Path, or do you want the folder path within InfoView?

Comment: First, we establish an Enterprise Connection and create a query of only Reports in an InfoStore (based on the Enterprise Connection), storing that query in an InfoObjects collection. Within a foreach loop based on this InfoObjects collection (of only reports), we instantiate a ReportDocument object. I'm wondering if there's any way to get the file path of that ReportDocument that exists on the Enterprise Server. For example, a file path might be "\\ReportSever\FolderName\ReportName.rpt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, this is how we came up with a solution for the problem.

All we use is a `StringBuilder` and an `InfoObject` query that looks like the following:

```
string sReportQueryString = 
    "SELECT SI_ID, SI_CUID, SI_NAME, SI_PATH, SI_PARENT_CUID " + 
    "FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS " + 
    "WHERE SI_PROGID='CrystalEnterprise.Report' AND SI_INSTANCE = 0";
```

After, we call our recursive method and execute the following code:

```
if (rptInfo.ParentID != 0)
{
    pathName.Insert(0, "\\" + rptInfo.Parent.ToString());
    getPath(rptInfo.Parent, ref pathName);
}
```

Where `rptInfo` is an `InfoObject` and `pathName` is a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible just from the InfoStore.  In your query you want to include the SI_FILES in the reply.  If you're already doing a *select * from CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_NAME='XYZ'* then you will already have it coming back.

The tricky part is that the SI_FILES property is in a property bag and has 2 parts that you care about:

1. SI_FILE1
2. SI_PATH

SI_FILE1 is the true file name as it was stored within the File Repository System (FRS).  The SI_PATH is the path of the file within the FRS.  The path will be similar to *frs://Input/a_135/028/000/7303/*  The first section *frs://Input* refers to the path as configured for the FRS inside the CMC.  The rest of the path is a regular filesystem path to where the SI_FILE1 is stored.